# How to create a pandas dataframe of unique values fetched from column with no duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
              "type" :["A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A"],
              "F_ID" :["0", "[7 8 9]", "[10]", "0", "[2]", "0", "0", "0", "0"]})
```

which looks like:

```
      F_ID  ID type
0        0   2    A
1  [7 8 9]   3    B
2     [10]   4    B
3        0   5    A
4      [2]   6    A
5        0   7    B
6        0   8    A
7        0   9    A
8        0  10    A
```

Here, F_ID is column which tells which records match with that articular records based on certain calculation. It gives the matching ID value. So ID 3 is matching with ID 7 and 8.

I wanted a list of all `B` type ID's and their associated records. with the matching ID mentioned in column F_ID in separate column, the no of such column 
can vary according to the values, like shown below:

```
ID  type F_ID_1  F_ID_2 
3    B    8      9
4    B    10      
7    B
```

I don't require the values of those F_ID mentioned which are of type B. For example ID 3 has 7, 8, 9 as matching IDs, but as the 7th ID is of type B that should not be mentioned as an F_ID and only 8 and 9 must be listed.

How can I do this with pandas in python ?

Comment: It's unclear to me how you know which values in each row of F_ID need to be saved

Comment: The Values in F_ID are the values of ID columns. so if the ID values mentioned in F_ID is having a type B, then we won't be putting that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your intent, F_ID is a string representation of a list?

If so, lets convert it to actual lists:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      "type" :["A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A"],
      "F_ID" :["0", "[7 8 9]", "[10]", "0", "[2]", "0", "0", "0", "0"]})

# convert the string representations of list structures to actual lists
F_ID_as_series_of_lists = df["F_ID"].str.replace("[","").str.replace("]","").str.split(" ")

#type(F_ID_as_series_of_lists) is pd.Series, make it a list for pd.DataFrame.from_records
F_ID_as_records = list(F_ID_as_series_of_lists)

f_id_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(F_ID_as_records)).fillna(np.nan)
f_id_df
```

[image: F_ID as List]

Now let's join the split `F_ID`s to the original DataFrame

```
combined_df = df.merge(f_id_df, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = "inner")
combined_df = combined_df.drop("F_ID", axis = 1).sort_values(["type", "ID"])
combined_df
```

[image: joined F_Ids]

However we need to omit the `F_ID`s that appear as in `ID` within the same `type`, i.e. As `7` is an `ID` in `type == "B"` we want to exclude it where `ID == 3` and `type == "B"`, even though it is in the list of `F_ID`s.

To achieve this let's create mapping of `ID`/`type` to `F_ID`.

```
mapping_df = pd.DataFrame(combined_df.set_index(["ID", "type"]).stack()).reset_index().drop("level_2", axis = 1)
mapping_df.columns = ["ID", "type", "F_ID"]
mapping_df
```

[image: mapping dataframe]

Now to do the filtering, we could probably do some impressive joining, but a query for this example is easier to read should we have to come back to this:

```
def is_fid_of_same_type(row, df):
    query = "ID == {row_fid} & type == '{row_type}'".format(
        row_fid = row["F_ID"],
        row_type = row["type"]
    )

    matches_df = df.query(query)

    row["fid_in_type_id"] = len(matches_df) > 0
    return row
```

Now apply this function to each row, and drop the rows that do appear as a `F_ID` as an `ID` within the same `type`.

```
df = mapping_df.apply(lambda row: is_fid_of_same_type(row, mapping_df), axis = 1)
df = df[df["fid_in_type_id"] == False].drop("fid_in_type_id", axis = 1)
df
```

[image: excluded the rows we want to exclude]

Then to have the `F_ID`s as a list rather than individual rows, use `DataFrame.groupby()` and then `apply(list)`.

```
group_columns = ['type', 'ID']
df = df.groupby(group_columns)['F_ID'].apply(list).reset_index()
df = df.sort_values(group_columns).set_index(group_columns)
df
```

Which results in:

[image: final result]

Comment: for ID 3, the value mentioned in F_ID is [7 8 9] so you have missed the 9. Also I don't need the F_ID 7 in front of ID 3 in the final output dataframe as 7 is of type B.

Comment: I used the code as in your question, so `F_ID` at index `1` aka ID 3 is `"[7 8]"`

Comment: sorry, I missed the value, made the edit in the question now.  also the F_ID 7 is not required in the ID 3 as that is of type B

Comment: Embellished some more which should be a good start towards what you're trying to achieve

Comment: In the final table, you have put the F_ID in different rows, how can I put them in a same row in different column ?

Comment: Cleaned up the answer given the feedback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174866/discussion-between-ryan-collingwood-and-archit).

Comment: I am getting an error `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()` , on running the line f_id_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(F_ID_as_records)).fillna(np.nan)